# Problems publishing synchronized topics

Tags: ros, syncronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish image synchronized topics using following code:

```
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>

using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;

void callback(const ImageConstPtr& left_image, const CameraInfoConstPtr& left_cam_info, const ImageConstPtr& right_image, const CameraInfoConstPtr& right_cam_info)
{
  // Solve all of perception here...
    printf("-----------------------\n");
    std::cout << "Time stamp (left image): "<< left_image->header.stamp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time stamp (right image): "<< right_image->header.stamp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time stamp (left camera info): "<< left_cam_info->header.stamp << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time stamp (right camera info): "<< right_cam_info->header.stamp << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "vizzy_sync_node");

  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  message_filters::Subscriber<Image> left_image_sub(nh, "vizzy/left/image_raw", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<CameraInfo> left_info_sub(nh, "vizzy/left/camera_info", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<Image> right_image_sub(nh, "vizzy/right/image_raw", 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<CameraInfo> right_info_sub(nh, "vizzy/right/camera_info", 1);

  TimeSynchronizer<Image, CameraInfo, Image, CameraInfo> sync(left_image_sub, left_info_sub, right_image_sub, right_info_sub, 10);
  sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2, _3, _4));    // cria 4 callbacks

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

but I see that the Callback function is not fired and don't know why. Anyone can help me and if possible tell me if in order to output the synchronized topics I can just publish them with simple advertise?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205385/problems-publishing-synchronized-topics/) by [aba92](https://answers.ros.org/users/21911/aba92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-03-19**:
Are you sure the time stamps do EXACTLY match? The TimeSynchronizer requires this for firing the callback, no epsilon allowed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know you should specify the sychronization policy, i.e.

```
#include "message_filters/subscriber.h"
#include "message_filters/synchronizer.h"
#include "message_filters/time_synchronizer.h"
#include "message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h"
#include <ros/callback_queue.h>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
```

Furthermore you should set a callback queue.

Example:
First:

```
using namespace message_filters;
ros::CallbackQueue my_callback_queue_;
message_filters::Subscriber<nav_msgs::Odometry> poseSub_;
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> laserSub_;
typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<nav_msgs::Odometry, sensor_msgs::LaserScan> MySyncPolicy;
typedef message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> Synchronizer;
boost::shared_ptr<Synchronizer> sync_;
```

Specify the message_filter subscriber:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh_;
poseSub_.subscribe(nh_, "/robot_pose", 1);
laserSub_.subscribe(nh_, "/scan", 1);
```

Then set the synchronizer:

```
sync_.reset(new Synchronizer(MySyncPolicy(10), poseSub_, laserSub_));
sync_->registerCallback(boost::bind(&emergency_handler::avoid, this, _1, _2));
nh_.setCallbackQueue(&my_callback_queue_);
```

Then, in order to spin the callback:

```
my_callback_queue_.callOne();
```

The code I posted is intended for a class use.I hope this helped...

PS: Sorry for my poor English...

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1